# Programmatically sending an IRC command

Tags: irc

Sending this to the server will join a channel:

`JOIN #channel-name`

This will send a message:

`PRIVMSG #channel-name :YOUR MESSAGE HERE`

How can I send a command?

In my IRC client, if I type /list, it will list all the channels. I try to send /list programmatically using PRIVMSG, but it literally sends /list and doesn't return channel names.

Comment: `/list` is not sent as a PRIVMSG to the server. Use the LIST command.

Comment: `ircsock.send('LIST')`:verne.freenode.net 421 Mybot LISTPRIVMSG :Unknown command

Comment: It sounds like you aren't sending `\r\n` after your LIST command.

Answer (score 1):

You send the string "LIST\r\n" to the socket using

```
socketname.send("LIST\r\n")
```

And then you wait for numeric 321, 322 and 323. *[IRC/2 Numeric List](https://www.alien.net.au/irc/irc2numerics.html)* lists the numerics you need to listen to and their format:

> 321    RPL_LISTSTART    RFC1459    Channels :Users Name    Channel list - Header 
> 322    RPL_LIST    RFC1459     <#_visible> :    Channel list - A channel 
> 323    RPL_LISTEND    RFC1459    :    Channel list - End of list